# How to use MySQL in async Node.JS

Tags: node.js, node-mysql

I come from PHP and do not understand how a series of MySQL queries can be written in async NodeJS. For example, take this example from `PHP` coding:

```
$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO articles (title) VALUES ('title')");
$article_id = $mysqli->insert_id;

foreach ($tags as $tag) {
    $result = mysqli->query("SELECT tag_id from tags WHERE tag='$tag'");
    if($result->num_rows==1){
        $row=$result->fetch_assoc();
        $tag_id=$row['tag_id'];
    } else {
        $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO tags (tag) VALUES ('$tag')");
        $tag_id=$mysqli->insert_id;
    }

    $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO tag_map (article_id, tag_id) VALUES ($article_id, $tag_id)");
}
```

How can we write this code in Node.JS?

I specifically mean, the if statement and getting `insert_id` for the next queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get insert id of latest record by this

```
 let query = "insert into `articles` (title) VALUES ('" + title + "')";

   db.query(query,(err,result) => {
      if(err){
           return res.status(500).send(err);
        }
         console.log(result.insertId)
   })
     .then((articleid)=>{
        tags.forEach((tag)=>{
         let tagQuery = "SELECT tag_id from tags WHERE tag='"+tag+"';
           // get tag_id from tags 
          db.query(query,(err,result) => {
          // if result length is greater tha 0
          if(result.length > 0){
             tag_id = result.tag_id // set tag id
           }
           else{
                // insert tag into db
                let insertTagQuery = "INSERT INTO tags (tag) VALUES ('"+tag+"')';
                db.query(insertTagQuery,(err,result) => {
                if(err){
                  return res.status(500).send(err);
                  }
                let mapTagQuery = 'INSERT INTO tag_map (article_id, tag_id) VALUES ('"+article_id+"', '"+result.tag_id+"')';

                db.query(mapTagQuery,(err,result) => {
                if(err){
                   return res.status(500).send(err);
                  }
                  console.log(result)
               });

             }

           console.log(result.insertId)
        })

       })
     }) ;
```

Comment: `node-mysql` was in my question tags. I know the module, I asked how to get multiple `insert_id` for the next query.

Comment: you can just simply `result.insertId` after insertion of every record it will return you the insert record id

Comment: I know, `result.insertId` return it. My question is how to continue the queries to insert tags and get their insert_id to use both `article_id` and `tag_id` to `INSERT` into `tag_map` table.

Comment: My problem is the loop after `let article_id = result.insertId`.